# Acessing derived members from vector of base type

Tags: c++, inheritance, radix, derived

Say I have some situation like this:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Position position;
    Normal   normal;
    Texcoord texcoord;
    int      boneID;
};

class VertexSkinned: public Vertex
{
public:
    float boneWeights[3];
    int   boneIDs[3];
};

class VertexMorphed: public Vertex
{
public:
    Position posTargets[3];
    Normal   normTargets[3];
    Texcoord texcoordTargets[3];
};

std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

VertexSkinned vs;
VertexMorphed vm;
Vertex        v;

vertices.push_back( vs );
vertices.push_back( vm );
vertices.push_back( v );

// This is illegal right? But how would I go about achieving the desired effect
float someFloat = vertices.front().boneWeights[2];
```

The question is in the comment. I rarely ever use inheritance and thought I might have found a beneficial use here, although it doesn't seem to be possible.

I assume using a vector of pointers and then dynamic casting to the derived class works? This isn't what I want to do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any other option other than storing the pointers and dynamic_cast later to get the derived object. If you want to do something like, can't you have 3 different vectors each with its own type. In that case, there is no need of the pointer business.

Comment: I ended up doing something like three different vectors.

The pragmatic considerations were out the window to begin with, because the idea was wrong headed. This was a purely theoretical question.

Answer (score 2):

you have a slice-ing  problem. sizeof(VertexSkinned) and  sizeof(VertexMorphed) are not equal with  sizeof(Vertex) and cannot be inserted in the array. Use pointers instead

To access a member of a derived class, first you must determine if the specified item is of derived type. One option will be to add in Base a GetType function or using dynamic_cast

Comment: Vectors aren't arrays, and according to VS2010 intellisense, they will accept the derived classes (I'm guessing they do some kind of cast in the push operation, or intellisense is just wrong). I know this sort of thing is possible with pointers - I'm just wondering if there is any way I can do something similar without them.

Comment: You don't know the type of the item. To access boneWeights you must some how cast to VertexSkinned. if you can have some default values for the boneWeights (if requested from a VertexSkinned or Vertex object) you can use virtual functions and make all calls to a Vertex object

Comment: No, you definitely can't do anything similar without them. push_back will accept the derived class, but it only copies the base part of it as cprogrammer has pointed out here.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a vertex array I suppose all the vertices in the array are of the same type which would mean that storing pointers and doing a `dynamic_cast` is a waste of time. When you know that every Vertex in the array is guaranteed to be, let's say a `VertexSkinned`, you should also be able to use a faster `static_cast`.

Storing pointers to individual vertices might be bad for performance since they won't be stored in one contiguous block of memory.